# Show my app on app store to some selected user only

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I want to install my app only on selected user's iPhone (100k users). Sharing app with development certificate is not possible there. So, I want my app on app store should be visible to only selected users.

Is it possible to mail a unique link to user then those user can only download/see my app on app store?

Comment: If only a selected ammount of people are allowed to have the app, why put it on the appstore?

Comment: Enterprise development might be helpful

Comment: @Tomm then how I will share app with my users as they are nearly in lakhs.

Comment: Lakhs? explain this please

Comment: Number of user are in lakh so sharing through development profile is not possible.

Comment: What does the word "lakh" mean ?

Comment: WHAT IS LAKH? Thats what i asked you

Comment: From google it means "100.000" in hindi. Considering he looks hindi, I think we're in the right and he wants to share with thousands of people by email. That might be conflicting with apple guidelines, he pretty much wants a private store for his app

Comment: Is it not possible to just send people the apk?

Comment: @Tomm Nope, not on iOS. Apple uses .ipa (they're like .apk), and if you signed with an entreprise certificate you can only share the .ipa manually (a private app for your enterprise that cannot be shared publicly). If you have a classic app store certificate, then it's the opposite, you can't share the .ipa manually, it must go on the app store (for the exception of beta testers)

Comment: Thats why i am living that android masterrace. Open source is so much more controlable imo

Comment: yes, lakh(lacs) means thousands of user I have.

Comment: @Gil Sand Thanks, this is what I need (entreprise certificate )

Comment: Yeah, you need entreprise certificate. But note that if those users are not all from the same "group" (= entreprise), you'll be violating apple guidelines. Entreprise *does not* mean you can publish your app on your own private store. The objective of entreprise is to publish a private app for your company for example, to handle private specific stuff about your company.
What you need exactly in the entreprise account is the Over-The-Air (OTA) way to publish your app.

Comment: I actually have another answer, look in my profile, you'll find the over-the-air answer and it's well explained there.

Comment: If people don't understand Indian words, don't you think you should both answer then and fix your question? Or is it somehow that people trying to help you must figure out whatever indian words you decide to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

If you have an entreprise account, that is even the only you can do. If you need to look it up I suggest you check "OTA" or "Over-The-Air" app publishing method. It's great and exactly for your situation. But if you're on the appstore that means you don't have an entreprise account, so I'll skip to the second solution straight away.

You need to have beta testers. In your iTunesConnect account, where you can manage all sorts of settings for your app, you should find a [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) tab. In this tab, you can set emails for people to beta test.

There are two types of testers,

**Internal testers**
They're a part of your development team, and they must be set as Admin or Manager or Tester to access the app. This would be done in the People tab in your developer.apple.com account. 25 users max.

**External testers**
**This is what you most probably need**
You can simply add up to 10.000 email addresses (that are linked to itunes accounts), and organize them in to groups if you want. You can also publish specific versions to specific groups.
In your case it might be simple "one app for all", so don't bother with groups yet.

All they have to do is install the testflight app, and they will be able to download the app from there. It's like a private appstore for them if you want.
If they don't have testflight, they'll receive an email with a link that will do the same.

Comment: I am not sure but i thought i read this somewhere, but doesn't TestFlight have a limit of only 100 devices.

Comment: No, that's your personal developer account. You can compile from xcode on 100 different pre-registered device in debug. That's included in your development certificate.
If you're using testflight, you're in release mode instead of debug, those devices are not included in the signing certificate. The only limit is the 10.000 users for external users. (which is enough for beta testing, but apparently not enough for the OP which wants something like a private store)

Comment: Looks like i learned something new today. Ty! (also nice blogs :) )

Comment: entreprise account is more helpfull ,as it does not have limits on number of user.

Comment: Yes, it's what you need. It also costs 300$/y instead of 100$ by the way

Comment: Feel free to upvote/mark answer if you found what you're looking for ;)